# debugg published site in vs2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, publishing

I published my web application to D:\Web\MyWebApp, how can I debug the published code using VS2008 ?
So the output will be the published code in 'D:\Web\MyWebApp'. I need to debug the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Host the published web site or web application in IIS. To do so, go to default web sites, create new virtual application, set physical path to 'D:\Web\MyWebApp'
2. Run the application by typing http://localhost/mywebapp/home.aspx
3. Keep running the site, go ot VS2008. Select "attach to process" from Debug menu.
4. You will see a "w3wp.exe", select it, click "Attach"
5. Create debug points on VS2008, you will get breaks on the points.